# How do I map cones on a grid using 5e standard distance?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, props

I am making spell templates for 5th editions standard distance rules, and I am puzzled on cones. How do you map large cones on a grid using the standard diagonal squares = 5ft rule?

I am mostly confused as to when the width equals the distance. The PHB just says "A cones width at a given point along it's distance is equal to that points distance from the origin.". I assume it is either the mid or end point, but either one has issues. If I choose the mid point it makes the cone huge, if I choose the end point the shape is off.

Either way, I know things like this are kept vague on purpose, but this seems a little to vague.

Comment: This might be a duplicate. Jack, does the question and its answer at that link solve your problem? If so, great! If not, could you add a diagram to your question illustrating the two versions — the “huge cone” and the “shape is off” versions? I can almost see where your difficulty is coming from, but I don't quite understand the two results you're getting, so I can't be certain where in the process it's gone wrong.